# python won't create thread?

Tags: python, windows, multithreading

I might be missing something silly, but ive ran my code in pythonwin and it works, but when I run it in command-line it freaks

```
import time, thread
def print_t(name, delay):
    while 1:
        time.sleep(delay)
        print name
try:
    thread.start_new_thread(print_t,("First Message",1,))
    thread.start_new_thread(print_t,("Second Message",2,))
except Exception as e:
    print e

Unhandled exception in thread started by
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr

Unhandled exception in thread started by
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

Comment: One thing you might like to know is that `import pdb;pdb.pm()` will open the debugger at the point of the last exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception happens when the main thread (the one that starts other threads) finishes. In your code the main thread quits before any of your sub threads (created by `start_new_thread`) finish. The solution is to wait at your main thread till the child threads ends.

See the discussion [Simple threading in Python 2.6 using thread.start_new_thread()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849674/simple-threading-in-python-2-6-using-thread-start-new-thread)

Answer (score 2):

It is because the main thread ends, and as you use `thread` insted of `threading`, the "child threads" die as well.

Better use the module `threading`.