# Python 2.7.5 Program Running Error

Tags: python, multithreading

So during my free time, i made a multi-threaded program that is somehow a cracker. What it does is that it reads a line from File1 and iterates through File2 , grabbing each line of data from File2 and sending the data i grabbed from File1 and File2 to a webpage and getting a specific response. Below is an example of what i did.

```
import urllib2
import thread
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()

def check(data1, data2):
     specificdata = "specific"
     dataone = data1.replace("\n", "")
     datatwo = data2.replace("\n", "")
     link = "http://webpage.com/?data1=" + dataone + "&data2=" + datatwo
     response = urllib.urlopen(link).read()
     lock.acquire()
     if specificdata in response:
         print "Success!"
     else:
         print "Failed!"
     lock.release()

data1list = raw_input("Data One List Path: ")
data2list = raw_input("Data Two List Path: ")
print ""
data1file = open(data1list, 'r')
for data1 in data1file:
    if data1 == "\n":
        break
    else:
        data2file = open(data2list, 'r')
        for data2 in data2file:
            if data2 == "\n":
                break
            else:
                    thread.start_new_thread(check,(data1, data2))
        data2file.close()
```

The code works in IDLE when i run it but it doesnt when i just double clicks the file as after i entered the paths, it just spams error messages ( not the "FAILED BEFORE CHECK()" or "FAILED IN CHECK()" ) and closes up before i can see what is going on. Any idea whats the problem?

----------------------**EDIT**---------------------

I managed to get the error and it says

Unhandled exception in thread started by
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr

Any idea how to solve this?

----------------------**SOLUTION**----------------------

[Simple threading in Python 2.6 using thread.start_new_thread()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849674/simple-threading-in-python-2-6-using-thread-start-new-thread)

Comment: Remove all the try...except so that you can see what exception is raised

Comment: What did you name the script?

Comment: I manage to get the error and it says                          Unhandled exception in thread started by
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr

Comment: I googled it up and look through Stackoverflow and i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849674/simple-threading-in-python-2-6-using-thread-start-new-thread , gonna try the solution and see if the problem is solved

Comment: The problem is finally solved ! Thanks for your help guys.