# Learning the Python Thread Module

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to learn more about the thread module.  I've come up with a quick script but am getting an error when I run it.  The docs show the format as:

```
thread.start_new_thread ( function, args[, kwargs] )
```

My method only has one argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ftplib
import thread

sites = ["ftp.openbsd.org","ftp.ucsb.edu","ubuntu.osuosl.org"]

def ftpconnect(target):
        ftp = ftplib.FTP(target)
        ftp.login()
        print "File list from: %s" % target
        files = ftp.dir()
        print files

for i in sites:
    thread.start_new_thread(ftpconnect(i))
```

The error I am seeing occurs after one iteration of the for loop:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./ftpthread.py", line 16,
>   in 
>       thread.start_new_thread(ftpconnect(i)) TypeError: start_new_thread expected at least 2 arguments, got 1

Any suggestions for this learning process would be appreciated.  I also looked into using threading, but I am unable to import threading since its not install apparently and I haven't found any documentation for installing that module yet.

Thank You!

There error I get when trying to import threading on my Mac is:

```
>>> import threading
# threading.pyc matches threading.py
import threading # precompiled from threading.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "threading.py", line 7, in <module>
    class WorkerThread(threading.Thread) :
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Thread'
```

Comment: Do not use `thread`.  It's low level, for expert use only.  `threading` is much more usable.  Show exactly what happens when you try `import threading`.  It's a standard library, so your installation is really screwed up ;-) if you can't import it.  Also please say which version of Python you're using, and which operating system.

Comment: see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849674/simple-threading-in-python-2-6-using-thread-start-new-thread

Comment: Looks like I can import threading on my Linux Mint install.  On my Mac, (2.7.5) I get a log error message ending with - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Thread'

Comment: Paste the exact code you used, and the entire traceback, into your question.  Format facilities in comments here are too feeble to show this.

Comment: It looks like you created *your own* module named `threading.py`.  Delete it or rename it, and also get rid of your `threading.pyc`.  Then `import threading` should work fine.

Comment: @tim: That Tim Peters? ... yeah i went to you bio-page  ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I wondered why I saw that .pyc file. I guess my creative file naming bit me :)

Comment: It's OK!  It happens to everyone, but *usually* with `random.py` :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `thread.start_new_thread` function is really low-level and doesn't give you a lot of control. Take a look at the `threading` module, more specifically the `Thread` class: http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects

You then want to replace the last 2 lines of your script with:

```
# This line should be at the top of your file, obviously :p
from threading import Thread 

threads = []
for i in sites:
    t = Thread(target=ftpconnect, args=[i])
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

# Wait for all the threads to complete before exiting the program.
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Your code was failing, by the way, because in your `for` loop, you were calling `ftpconnect(i)`, waiting for it to complete, and *then* trying to use its return value (that is, `None`) to start a new thread, which obviously doesn't work.

In general, starting a thread is done by giving it a callable object (function/method -- you want the callable object, *not* the result of a call -- `my_function`, not `my_function()`), and optional arguments to give the callable object (in our case, `[i]` because `ftpconnect` takes one positional argument and you want it to be `i`), and then calling the `Thread` object's `start` method.

Answer (score 3):

Now that you can import `threading`, start with best practices at once ;-)

```
import threading
threads = [threading.Thread(target=ftpconnect, args=(s,))
           for s in sites]
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:  # shut down cleanly
    t.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to pass the function object and arguments to the function to `thread.start_new_thread`, not execute the function.

Like this:

```
for i in sites:
    thread.start_new_thread(ftpconnect, (i,))
```

Comment: When I make these changes, my script runs without any errors, but I don't get any output to the console.